# Unable to create new Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm unable to create a new database for the first time after installing postgres.app on my macbook pro
[image]

Anyone here can point me to the origin of the problem ?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Copy and paste raw text.

Answer (score 6):

`createdb` is ***not*** a SQL statement, it's program for the command line (like `psql` or `grep`).

Inside `psql` you need to use the SQL statement `CREATE DATABASE`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html

And don't forget to terminate **every** SQL statement with a `;` (if you had done that with `createdb` you would have gotten an error message immediately).